# WPF - Adding a handler for PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown suppresses click event

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

Just adding a handler for PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown seems to suppress the button's click event. Is this to be expected? My understanding was that this would only happened if marked the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event args as handled then further handlers wouldn't be invoked but I haven't done that. I checked the value of e.Handled in the handler for PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and it's false. What's going on here?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="169.604" Width="233.59">
      <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Click="button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click event");
        }

        private void button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you don't show a MessageBox, but just generate some debug output like `Debug.WriteLine("PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` does not supress `Click` event. It's what you are doing inside that handler can supress `Click` event under certain conditions. Button has `ClickMode` property with possible options `Release`, `Press` and `Hover`. Default one is `Release`. For `Click` event to fire in `Release` mode mouse should press the button (mouse down) and release (mouse up). In your case button is pressed but then message box appears, button loses mouse capture and no "mouse up" event is registered. Without "mouse up" event (for which `MouseLeftButtonUp` is handler) - `Click` event is not registered in `Release` mode. If you replace `MessageBox.Show` with something that does not grabs focus (like `Console.WriteLine`) or change button `ClickMode` to `Press` - code will work as expected.

Ensure also that you don't have breakpoints in `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event handler also - because breaking on it will bring focus to visual studio and click event will not work again.